# Change NTFS Security via Powershell

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I'm looking for a simple Powershell way to set NTFS permissions on a specific folder.

`Get-Acl "\\fileserver\c$\Program Files\Target"` is not even working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Either way, you have not posted enough information with this question for us to help you.

Comment: You should tell us *why* isn't not working. What error do you get, etc? Take a peek at [ask], it will help you ask a useful question that can be valuable to others.

Comment: In addition to How to Ask, please take a look at [this meta question](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) which may help you improve this question.  If you can edit this question to include enough information for us to help you leave a comment for me and I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is use `get-acl` and save it to a variable. Then, you can modify that variable and push it to the file/folder in question using `set-acl`

There are some [good examples here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849810.aspx) and [even more examples here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx).

If that's too complicated (it can get a bit messy at times), you can always just call `icacls.exe` from your PowerShell script and do it the old-fashioned way.